# How to run a task against a list of hosts in fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I use Python 2.6 / Fabric 1.8.0 and I have several hosts containing different local path and variable.

```
import 
....

def vmm_two_a():
  env.hosts = 'xxx.xx.xx.xx'
  env.user = 'tom'
  env.password = password_from_netrc(env.hosts,env.user)
  global local_path
  local_path = '/home/vmm_two_a/binaries'

def vmm_two_mgmt():
  env.hosts = 'xxx.xx.xx.xx'
  env.user = 'john'
  env.password = password_from_netrc(env.hosts,env.user)
  global local_path
  local_path = '/home/vmm_two_mgmt/binaries'


def get_etc_binaries():
''' Get all etc binaries deployed '''
with hide('stderr','stdout','output','running', 'warnings'):
    settings(warn_only=True)
    get('/usr/local/etc', local_path)
```

How to run this task against all hosts? I've tried fab -H with no success.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In this instance you'd need to call the task setting the env vars before the get_etc_binaries task each time. You might also make local_path be env.local_path, so it's shared easier.

Call like this would look like: fab vmm_twomgmt get_etc_binaries vmm_two_a get_etc_binaries